# Possible to truncate strings from a YAML file in Middleman?

Tags: ruby, yaml, middleman

I'm generating YAML files that I'm iterating through to create cards on a page.

One of the fields in the YAML file is a text field that has a highly variable length.

In order to have a predictable amount of text being displayed in the view (I'm creating cards with equal heights), I'd like to truncate the string to x characters.

When working within blogs, one has access to the [.summary method](https://middlemanapp.com/basics/blogging/#article-summaries), but I get a no method error when trying to use it outside of the blog part of my Middleman site.

Is there another simple way to achieve this? Have also tried with the truncate method, but that doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the loop in case it's helpful.

```
        <% data.jobs.each do |j| %>
        <div class="col job-card">
            <div class="job-card-heading">
                <img src="/assets/images/latest-jobs/<%= j.image %>" alt="Company Logo">
                <div class="job-heading-text">
                    <h3><%= j.company %></h3>
                    <span><%= j.location %></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="job-card-body">
                <h3><%= j.name %></h3>
                <p><%= j.description.summary(125) %></p>
            </div>
            <div class="job-card-body">
                <span class="job-type"><%= j.jobtype %></span>
                <span class="clinician-type"><%= j.cliniciantype %></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncate should work for this:

```
<%= truncate(j.description, :length => 125) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `description` variable is a string try using:

```
<%= j.description.first(125) %>
```

Comment: Yep. I ended up just creating another data field that's 175 characters with an ellipsis on the end.